# T-SQL Full Outer Join Statement not including unique values from joined table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-outer-join

I have a T-SQL statement that is supposed to do a `Full OUTER JOIN`.

I'll call the original select statement `table1`, I'll call the joined table `table2`.

My query is not returning values that are unique in `table2` . More specifically, it is not returning rows where table2 has a segValue1 or segValue2 that is not in table1. (i.e. it is erroneously acting as if the join is a `LEFT JOIN` and not `FULL OUTER JOIN`).

I can't figure out why it's doing this. Why would this be behaving as if it were a left join??

Basically what is happening, is if the account has no activity/does not exist in the Actuals table, then it's not being picked up.

Here is an example of Table A, Table B, current results Table, and desired results  table:

```
Table Actual (SQL Server table with Actuals)
company  segValue1  segValue2 ActualsAmount FiscalYear FiscalPeriod
NVV        5000        000        $20         2017         12
NVV        6000        111        $100        2017         12
NVV        8000        333        $40         2017         12
NVV        4000        555        $200        2017         12


Table Budget (SQL Server table with Budgets)
company  segValue1  segValue2  BudgetAmt BalanceType FiscalYear FiscalPeriod
NVV        5000        000        $10        D          2017        12
NVV        2000        111        $50        D          2017        12
NVV        8000        444        $90        D          2017        12
NVV        4000        555        $60        D          2017        12


Table that the current, erroneous Code is producing. 
Notice it is skipping records 2 and 3 from Table B because it is not in Table A:

company  segValue1  segValue2     ActualsAmount       BudgetAmt
NVV        5000        000              $20              $10                   
NVV        6000        111              $100             NULL                
NVV        8000        333              $40              NULL  
NVV        8000        333              $40              NULL              
NVV        4000        555              $200             $60   


Desired Result Table:
company  segValue1  segValue2     ActualsAmount       BudgetAmt
NVV        5000        000              $20              $10                   
NVV        6000        111              $100             NULL   
NVV        2000        111              NULL              $50       --<-correct            
NVV        8000        444              NULL              $90       --<-correct    
NVV        8000        333              $40              NULL                
NVV        4000        555              $200             $60
```

Here is the code:

```
SELECT 
    A.Company, 
    A.segvalue1, A.segvalue2,      
    APYY.BalanceAmtBYTD, APYY.BalanceAmtBM, 
    SUM(CASE 
           WHEN FiscalPeriod BETWEEN '1' AND '12' AND FiscalYear = '2017' 
              THEN ActualsAmount 
              ELSE NULL 
        END) AS BalanceAmtCYTD, 
    SUM(CASE 
           WHEN FiscalPeriod = '12' AND FiscalYear = '2017' 
              THEN ActualsAmount
              ELSE NULL 
        END) AS BalanceAmtCYM
FROM 
    Actual  A

FULL OUTER JOIN

(SELECT 
         B.Company, B.segvalue1, B.segvalue2, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN FiscalPeriod BETWEEN '1' AND '12' AND FiscalYear = '2017' THEN BudgetAmt ELSE NULL END) as BalanceAmtBYTD, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN FiscalPeriod = '12' AND FiscalYear = '2017' THEN BudgetAmt ELSE NULL END) as BalanceAmtBM 
    FROM 
        Budget B 
    WHERE 
        FiscalYear = '2017' 
        AND BalanceType LIKE '%D%' 

    GROUP BY 
        B.Company, 
        B.segvalue1, B.segvalue2 ) APYY ON (A.Company = APYY.Company 
                                             AND A.segvalue1 = APYY.segvalue1 
                                             AND A.segvalue2 = APYY.segvalue2) 
WHERE 
    A.Company = 'NVV' 
GROUP BY 
    A.Company,  A.segvalue1,  A.segvalue2,
    APYY.BalanceAmtBYTD, APYY.BalanceAmtBM
```

Comment: I certainly haven't seen anything yet that "hits me in the face like a baseball bat"!

Comment: Try putting both tables into temp tables and doing full join then.

Comment: Any where against an outer join will exclude rows. GLJ is filtered on one company and APPY is filtered on another

Comment: by any chance, are your where statements filtering particular rows?? can u remove where temporarily and verify?

Comment: @Raska I commented out both where statements and it is still excluding unique rows from table2 !

Comment: Suggest you use the table names of the query

Comment: @Paparazzi, I clarified the Table names. I think this is what you were looking for?

Comment: This clause `WHERE 
        FiscalYear = '2017' 
        AND BalanceType LIKE '%D%' ` references columns that you haven’t shown us and could cause this problem.  I’m guessing the BalanceType.

Comment: @RBarryYoung , I added those columns to the applicable tables. Let me know if you need more info please

Comment: No FiscalPeriod.  I give up.  No way you actually tested this.

Comment: Table does not match the query so we have no way to test.  What about NVV, 8000,  444?  VTC

Comment: Yeah, we cannot help you with this because you are hiding the parts that are causing the problem from us.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I added the treatment of NVV 8000 444   to the tables

Comment: hey Thanks for trying guys. have a good one!

Comment: Query still does not run on posted data.   You have a problem with breaking down a problem and writing a problem statement.

Comment: @Paparazzi FiscalPeriod added. my apologies i did not realize people actually are running the data. I thought it was more of a conceptual thing. I understand now. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an article that helped me figure it out. Basically I decided to use a Union All and just address the "same column name" and "equal number of columns" union  specific requirements issue by making "dummy" columns and setting them to zero, then group at the end. This weekend was a huge learning experience for me. I learned more about tsql this weekend then I have my entire time studying it. Here's  the article where I discovered this technique/structure "Better alternatives to outer joins": http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/04/19/Full-Outer-Joins.aspx

Here's my final T-SQL:

```
select 
Company,
segValue1,
segValue2,
segValue3,
segvalue4,


SUM(BalanceAmtCYTD) as BalanceAmtCYTD,
    SUM(BalanceAmtCYM) as BalanceAmtCYM,
    SUM(BalanceAmtAPYTD) as BalanceAmtAPYTD, 
    SUM(BalanceAmtBSPYBal) as BalanceAmtBSPYBal, 
    SUM(BalanceAmtBSCYBal) as BalanceAmtBSCYBal,
    SUM(BalanceAmtBSCYActivity) as BalanceAmtBSCYActivity,
    SUM(BalanceAmtBSCMActivity) as BalanceAmtBSCMActivity, 
    SUM(BalanceAmtAPYM) as BalanceAmtAPYM,
    SUM(BalanceAmtBYTD) as BalanceAmtBYTD,
    SUM(BalanceAmtBM) as BalanceAmtBM

From
(


Select
Company,
segValue1,
segValue2,
segValue3,
segvalue4,

SUM(CASE WHEN FiscalPeriod BETWEEN '1' AND '3' AND FiscalYear = '2018' THEN DebitAmount - CreditAmount END) as BalanceAmtCYTD, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN FiscalPeriod = '3' AND FiscalYear = '2018' THEN DebitAmount - CreditAmount  END) as BalanceAmtCYM, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN FiscalPeriod BETWEEN '1' AND '3' AND FiscalYear = '2017' THEN DebitAmount - CreditAmount  END) as BalanceAmtAPYTD, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ((FiscalPeriod between '1' AND '3' AND FiscalYear = '2017') OR (FiscalYear < '2017')) THEN DebitAmount - CreditAmount  END) as BalanceAmtBSPYBal, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ((FiscalPeriod between '1' AND '3' AND FiscalYear = '2018') OR (FiscalYear < '2018')) THEN DebitAmount - CreditAmount  END) as BalanceAmtBSCYBal, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN (FiscalPeriod between '1' AND '3') AND (FiscalYear = '2018') THEN DebitAmount - CreditAmount END) as BalanceAmtBSCYActivity, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN (FiscalPeriod = '3') AND (FiscalYear = '2018') THEN DebitAmount - CreditAmount END) as BalanceAmtBSCMActivity, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN (FiscalPeriod = '3') AND (FiscalYear = '2017') THEN DebitAmount - CreditAmount END) as BalanceAmtAPYM,
    0 as BalanceAmtBYTD,
    0 as BalanceAmtBM

    FROM GLJrnDtl
    where company = 'ovpca'
group by Company,
segValue1,
segValue2,
segValue3,
segvalue4

Union all

Select
Company,
segValue1,
segValue2,
segValue3,
segvalue4,

0 as BalanceAmtCYTD,
0 as BalanceAmtCYM,
0 as BalanceAmtAPYTD,
0 as BalanceAmtBSPYBal,
0 as BalanceAmtBSCYBal,
0 as BalanceAmtBSCYActivity, 
0 as BalanceAmtBSCMActivity,
0 as BalanceAmtAPYM,

SUM(CASE WHEN  FiscalPeriod BETWEEN '1' AND '3' AND FiscalYear = '2018' THEN BudgetAmt ELSE NULL END) as BalanceAmtBYTD, 
SUM(CASE WHEN FiscalPeriod = '3' AND FiscalYear = '2018' THEN BudgetAmt ELSE NULL END) as BalanceAmtBM


from GLBudgetDtl
where Company = 'ovpca' and balancetype = 'd'

group by Company,
segValue1,
segValue2,
segValue3,
segvalue4
) x

Group by
Company,
segValue1,
segValue2,
segValue3,
segvalue4
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is breaking it

```
WHERE GLJ.Company = 'NVV'
```

This is not just the answer but how to approach a problem

```
declare @TableA table (Company varchar(5), segValue1 int, segValue2 int, ActualAmount int, FiscalYear int, FiscalPeriod int);
declare @TableB table (Company varchar(5), segValue1 int, segValue2 int, BudgetAmt int,    FiscalYear int, FiscalPeriod int);

insert into @TableA values 
             ('NVV', 5000, 000, 20, 2017, 12)
           , ('NVV', 6000, 111, 100, 2017, 12)
           , ('NVV', 8000, 333, 40, 2017, 12)
           , ('NVV', 4000, 555, 200, 2017, 12); 

insert into @TableB values 
             ('NVV', 5000, 000, 10, 2017, 12)
           , ('NVV', 2000, 111, 50, 2017, 12)
           , ('NVV', 8000, 444, 90, 2017, 12)
           , ('NVV', 4000, 555, 60, 2017, 12); 


select * from @TableA order by Company, segvalue1, segvalue2;

SELECT  B.Company, B.segvalue1, B.segvalue2, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN FiscalPeriod BETWEEN '1' AND '12' AND FiscalYear = '2017' THEN BudgetAmt ELSE NULL END) as BalanceAmtBYTD, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN FiscalPeriod = '12' AND FiscalYear = '2017' THEN BudgetAmt ELSE NULL END) as BalanceAmtBM 
FROM  @TableB B 
WHERE FiscalYear = '2017' 
GROUP BY B.Company, B.segvalue1, B.segvalue2 
ORDER BY B.Company, B.segvalue1, B.segvalue2; 

select isnull(A.Company, bb.Company) as Company, isnull(A.segvalue1, bb.segValue1) as segvalue1, isnull(A.segvalue2, bb.segValue2) as segvalue2, 
       bb.BalanceAmtBYTD, bb.BalanceAmtBM 
from @TableA a
full outer join ( SELECT  B.Company, B.segvalue1, B.segvalue2, 
                          SUM(CASE WHEN FiscalPeriod BETWEEN '1' AND '12' AND FiscalYear = '2017' THEN BudgetAmt ELSE NULL END) as BalanceAmtBYTD, 
                          SUM(CASE WHEN FiscalPeriod = '12' AND FiscalYear = '2017' THEN BudgetAmt ELSE NULL END) as BalanceAmtBM 
                    FROM  @TableB B 
                   WHERE  FiscalYear = '2017' 
                   GROUP BY  B.Company, B.segvalue1, B.segvalue2
                 ) bb
  on a.Company   = bb.Company
 and a.segValue1 = bb.segValue1
 and a.segValue2 = bb.segValue2
group by A.Company,   A.segvalue1,   A.segvalue2,  
         bb.Company,  bb.segvalue1,  bb.segvalue2,
         bb.BalanceAmtBYTD, bb.BalanceAmtBM 
order by isnull(A.Company, bb.Company), isnull(A.segvalue1, bb.segValue1), isnull(A.segvalue2, bb.segValue2);
```

Comment: I commented that out and It is still excluding unique records from table2

Comment: Try and reproduce with a simple example with data.

Comment: I simplified the query and added  explanatory tables. Thank you

Comment: @Paparazzi consider removing your answer and making it a comment

Comment: @Kermit A comment is ask for clarification.

Comment: @Kermit So that makes it an incorrect answer.  A comment is to ask for more information and not answer.  This is clearly not a request for information.